# When I start a local server I cannot access it from different devices connected to the same network

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, firewall

I am trying to access my js server from different devices on the same internet. I got my Ipv4 address and typed that into my browser with :8080 because that is the port but it does not find the page.

```
var http = require("http");



http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}).listen(8080, "0.0.0.0")
```

What am I doing wrong? Nodejs can communicate through my firewall.
Thanks

Comment: This happened to me once, turns out I couldn't connect any other devices because I'd forgotten to turn my hotspot off 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want wireless connection then you can use your adopter ip address. To get ip address go cmd and type ipconfig then copy ip4 which is like 194.98.68.1.replace it with 0.0.0.0

Or if you want to connect world wide then you can use tunnels. These are popular tunnels: ngrok, Vortex, serveo etc. first step local host your nodejs then open ngrok then type http 8080 and press enter then they will give a port forward address which is like http://14ft566huigrthiyrg/ngrok. Now you can put this in any device world wide.

Comment: When I replace 0.0.0.0 with the ip4 the script just errors. Not my scripts but the nodejs scripts error.

Comment: Can you what is the error showing @henberrysodapop

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure Port was listening with your Machine
netstat -ntulp | grep 8080

Try to telnet from different Machine
Telnet Your machine IP 192.168.1.10 8080
or Traceroute the machine from different workstation
traceroute -d you Workstation ip

Check your Windows/linux  Firewall too

Please let us know the above outputs if possible